# calling a Fragment from a button in a listview Item

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I Have a `ListView` in a `Fragment`, in my ListView's Item, i have a `Button` How can i call another `Fragment` a custom `DialogFragment` from clicking on the button and keep the item information?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: well i showed it yesterday i got 6 downvote without a comment, so it is not very constructive, so i am trying to ask a general question, maybe a did i big mistake in the logic step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Use interface ,
Create an Interface in Adapter class , then set it from owner fragment and when user click on Button call interface Method

Adapter class :

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private ArrayList<AddressModel> dataset;
private WeakReference<Activity> activity;
private onChecked listener;

public TestAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<AddressModel> datasett) {
    this.dataset = datasett;
    this.activity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(activity.get()).inflate(R.layout.item_popup_change_address_step_two, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title_itemPopUp_ChangeAddress_TV);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    tv.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(parent.getContext(), R.drawable.edittext_style));
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new ViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.title.get().setText(dataset.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.rootView.get().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) //call interface 
                listener.chekedListener(dataset.get(position));
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (dataset == null)
        return 0;
    return dataset.size();
}

public void setListener(onChecked listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface onChecked {
    void chekedListener(AddressModel addressClass_serialized);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private WeakReference<TextView> title;
    private WeakReference<LinearLayout> rootView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = new WeakReference<TextView>((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_itemPopUp_ChangeAddress_TV));
        rootView = new WeakReference<LinearLayout>((LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootCardView_addressItemPopUP_cd));
    }
}
```

}

in fragment :

```
adapter.setListener(new TestAdapter.onChecked() {
        @Override
        public void chekedListener(AddressModel addressClass_serialized) {
            //Call Dialog Here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logic/Steps**

Set the Click Listener in List Items.

**Step 1:-** Make Constructor in DialogFragment/CustomDialog to pass the Information from OnClick of ListItem.

**Step 2:-** Do whatevet u want in Dialog Class.